Seek the maximum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{25} (x_i^3 - x_i x_{i+1}x_{i+2})$ subject to $0 \le x_i \le i, \forall i$

Problem.  Let $0 \le x_i \le i, i = 1, 2, \cdots, 25$. Seek the maximum of
$$S = x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \cdots + x_{25}^3
- (x_1x_2x_3 + x_2x_3x_4 + \cdots + x_{25}x_1x_2).$$

According to @achille hui's nice answer,
the maximum is $75824$ when
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_{25})$$
$$ =  ( 0, 0, 3, 4,  0, 6, 7, 0, 9, 10, 0,12,13, 0,15,16, 0,18,19, 0,21,22, 0,24,25).$$
Source. This is related to Q1(marked as duplicate) and Q2.
According to the comment in Q1 above,
this was a problem in a mock math competition.
I think there are a simpler or contest style solutions.
Motivation. In Q2 above, @achille hui gave a nice answer for general $n$ and also the special case $n=25$. However, @achille hui's solution is not a contest style solutions. I have found a simpler solution for at least the case $n=25$ (see my answer below). Furthermore, I think my approach can be extended to the general $n$ i.e. Q2. Anyway, I think the case $n=25$ itself is an interesting problem. Though I don't have an access to the official solution, I believe there are more nice solutions.
My solution. After I posted my question, I made some effort to come up with a solution (see my answer below).

Probably involves some grouping of 4 or something, perhaps taking 3 cubes and their respective product?

@Kraken Yes, I also think that grouping is helpful.

@Kraken Thanks for your attention. I have found a simpler solution. However, a bad news is that there are 4 votes for closure.

Here is a simpler solution.
When $x_1 = 0$, and
$(x_{3i+2}, x_{3i+3}, x_{3i+4}) = (0, 3i+3, 3i+4)$ for $i = 0, 1, \cdots, 7$, we have $S = 75824$.
Let us prove that $75824$ is the maximum of $S$.
First, we give the following auxiliary result. The proof is given at the end.
Fact 1: Let $p\ge 1$ be fixed. Let $a\in [0, p]$ and $b\in [0, p+1]$
and $c \in [0, p+2]$. Then $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - abc \le (p+1)^3 + (p+2)^3$.
Now, we proceed. we split into two cases.
Case 1. $x_{24}x_{25} \ge 1$
We have
$$S(0, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{25}) - S(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{25})$$
$$= - x_1^3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_{25}x_1 x_2 + x_{24}x_{25}x_1 \ge 0$$
where we use $x_1 \in [0, 1]$.
By Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 S(0, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{25}) &\le \sum_{i=0}^7 (x_{3i+2}^3 + x_{3i+3}^3 + x_{3i+4}^3 - x_{3i+2}x_{3i+3}x_{3i+4})\\
 &\le \sum_{i=0}^7 \Big((3i+3)^3 + (3i+4)^3\Big)\\
 &= 75824.
\end{align*}
Thus, $S(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{25}) \le 75824$.
Case 2. $x_{24}x_{25} < 1$
We can prove that $x_{24}^3 + x_{25}^3 < 1^3 + 25^3 = 15626$.
Indeed, if $x_{25} \ge 1$, we have $x_{24}^3 + x_{25}^3 \le \frac{1}{x_{25}^3} + x_{25}^3 \le \frac{1}{25^3} + 25^3 < 1 + 25^3$; and if $x_{25} < 1$, we have $x_{24}^3 + x_{25}^3
\le 24^3 + 1^3 < 15626$.
By Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 S(x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_{25})
 &\le x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_{24}^3 + x_{25}^3 \\
 &\qquad + \sum_{i=0}^6 \Big(x_{3i+3}^3 + x_{3i+4}^3 + x_{3i+5}^3 - x_{3i+3}x_{3i+4}x_{3i+5}\Big)\\
 &\le 1^3 + 2^3 + 15626 + \sum_{i=0}^6 \Big((3i+4)^3 + (3i+5)^3\Big)\\
 &= 70634\\
 &< 75824.
\end{align*}
In summary, the desired result follows.
$\phantom{2}$

Proof of Fact 1:
We have
\begin{align*}
 a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - abc &\le p^2 a + (p+1)^2 b + (p+2)^2 c - abc \\
 &= p^2a + (p+1)^2b + [(p + 2)^2 - ab]c\\
 &\le p^2a + (p+1)^2b + [(p + 2)^2 - ab]\cdot (p + 2)\\
 &= (p+2)^3 + p^2a + [(p+1)^2 - a(p+2)]b\\
 &\le (p+2)^3 + p^2a + [(p+1)^2 - a(p+2)]\cdot (p+1)\\
 &= (p+1)^3 + (p+2)^3 - [(p+1)(p+2) - p^2]a\\
 &\le (p+1)^3 + (p+2)^3.
\end{align*}
